# Search type JSONPath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I use JSONpath but despite my research I don't find some response.

Look at one exemple of my object

```
  "definitions" : {
    "person" : {
      "properties" : {
        "person_id" : {
          "format" : "int32",
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "birth_date" : {
          "format" : "date-time",
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "sur_name" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "first_name" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      },
      "type" : "object"
    }
  },
```

And i am currently using this path : **$.[*].type**

And my result is

```
[
  "object",
  "integer",
  "string",
  "string",
  "string"
]
```

But I want to show only my **"string"** type and I don't know how

I use that docs https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Thank you ! :)

Comment: Have you tried adding a == filter?

Answer (score 0):

`$..[?(@.type == 'string')].type` this will show as follow. Is that what you want?

```
[
  "string",
  "string",
  "string"
]
```

Comment: I think OP wants to only get strings